# How are probabilities defined?

Tags: probability

This stray thought has been bothering me for the past week. It seems that all probabilities and percentages are defined using the extremes 0% and 100%.

Where:

- 0% is the probability that something will never happen
- 100% is the probability of something that will definitely happen

and from a layman's point of view all other probabilities seem to lie somewhere in between these two extremes.

However these two extremes seem too vague or ill defined to be used to define any other values since you cannot assert that something is impossible. i.e. you can say that something is improbable, but difficult to say something is impossible.

So my question would be how are probabilities rigorously defined without resorting to the extremes of 0% and 100%?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that they are rigorously defined *exactly* by resorting to the extremes of $0$ and $100$ percent.  The so-called *sigma algebras* that provide the probability basis for a given situation always admit event sets of nothing ($0$ percent) and everything ($100$ percent).  Everything else is between, as you say.  And, in a sense, the probability of any event is what we define it, or determine it, to be.

That may not be very satisfying from a practical point of view, since (as you observe) we can rarely say that anything is utterly impossible, or utterly certain.  That is not really the aim of probability, however, even practically speaking.  The objective is not to determine that two children are both male with probability $1/4$, but to determine that *if* children are born male or female with equal probability, *and* their genders are independent, *then* the probability that both are male is $1/4$.  In other words, it is not the conclusion that is the fruit of applied probability, but the transfer from input knowledge to output knowledge.

That is, to be sure, the aim of much of applied mathematics: not the ultimate discoveries, but the line of reasoning that one follows to arrive there.

Answer (score 0):

In rigorously defining probabilities, there are two main schools of thought: frequentist probability and Bayesian probability.

The former states that probability is simply how often something typically happens when you "sample" it. In that sense, probability is *defined* as the expected frequency of an event when sampled. This can be 100% or 0%, but typically isn't.

The latter states that probability is more of a human metric for taking what we know and building on it. Probability is not a universal thing in this sense: it's not exactly how often something will happen, but it's what we believe given the information we have. This can also be 100% or 0%, but typically isn't.

Wikipedia explains the difference between the two ideas succinctly:

> Bayesian probability is one interpretation of the concept of probability. In contrast to interpreting probability as the "frequency" or "propensity" of some phenomenon, Bayesian probability is a quantity that we assign for the purpose of representing a state of knowledge, or a state of belief. In the Bayesian view, a probability is assigned to a hypothesis, whereas under the frequentist view, a hypothesis is typically tested without being assigned a probability.

As such, you don't need the 0% and 100% definitions to define either definition of probability, yet they encapsulate the ideas of 0% and 100% at the same time. For example, frequentists state that 0% probability means that the event at hand will indeed never happen, whereas Bayesianists state that 0% probability means that according to the information given, there is a belief that the event will never occur.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering extremes probability is the limit of the ratio of the number of experimental outcomes of interest to the total number of trials as the total number of trials tend towards infinity.

However the ordinary definition states that if $ \Omega $ is the sample space of a random experiment any member of the sigma field on $ \Omega $ is called the event $ E $. Then the number $P(E)$ assigned to any event $ E $ will be probability measures if it satisfies the following axioms

1. $ P(E)$ is a measurable function
2. $ P( \Omega ) $ is 1.